# Google Places JS API weekday_text

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Does anyone know why my "nearbySearch" google place search is missing data?

When I do a nearby search using the places API, every weekday_text array returns as empty but when I do a "getDetails" request to one of the locations in the initial search, the weekday_text is returned.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGBVJR

```js
var map;
var service;

// Nearby search
var showPosition = function() {

  var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5074, -0.1278);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: geolocation,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: geolocation,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['bar']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

};
showPosition();

function callback(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results);
  }

}

// Direct location check
function altTest() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5074, -0.1278),
    zoom: 15
  });

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails({
    placeId: 'ChIJ78fbAc8EdkgRWG1dhffz9AY'
  }, function (place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      console.log(place.opening_hours.weekday_text);
    }
  });

}

altTest();
```

```html
<div id="map">
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Please see the console.logs to see the data discrepancy.

Any ideas why this is the case? I would rather not have to do a second API request to retrieve the weekday requests.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nearbySearch returns an array of PlaceResult objects.

As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult), PlaceResult doesn't have weekday_text property.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation also states that a details request returns the same type of object.  I would say the documentation is out of date.

Comment: Its starting to look like I will need to do many api calls. Has anyone found an efficient way to do this?